# How to write async data to remote endpoint without getting "No suitable writer found exception"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have the following controller method:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, path = "/upload")
public Mono<SomeResponse> saveEnhanced(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> file) {
    return documentService.save(file);
}
```

which calls a service method where I try to use a WebClient to put some data in another application:

```
public Mono<SomeResponse> save(Mono<FilePart> file) {
    MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    bodyBuilder.asyncPart("file", file, FilePart.class);
    bodyBuilder.part("identifiers", "some static content");
    return WebClient.create("some-url").put()
            .uri("/remote-path")
            .syncBody(bodyBuilder.build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(SomeResponse.class);

}
```

but I get the error:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: No suitable writer found for part: file
```

I tried all variants of the **MultipartBodyBuilder** (part, asyncpart, with or without headers) and I cannot get it to work.

Am I using it wrong, what am I missing?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Did you try adding correct content-type header to your WebClient HTTP request?
Spring tries to serialize `FilePart` to JSON by default and fails.

Comment: I finally found the issue combining a response from one of the contributors of Spring and additional information from another source. I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution after getting a reply from one of the contributes on the Spring Framework Github issues section.
For this to work:

> The asyncPart method is expecting actual content, i.e. file.content(). I'll update it to unwrap the part content automatically.

```
bodyBuilder.asyncPart("file", file.content(), DataBuffer.class)
    .headers(h -> {
        h.setContentDispositionFormData("file", file.name());
        h.setContentType(file.headers().getContentType());
    });
```

If both headers are not set then the request will fail on the remote side, saying it cannot find the form part.

Good luck to anyone needing this!